# Cannot pass a input from text box to a query string and then keep the string in this box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple ASP.net page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <p><asp:TextBox id="input_box" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

       <asp:Button Text="OK" runat="server" OnClick="run" /></p>
 </form>
```

I want to send input from input_box to a query string, and then keep this input in the input_box when the page reloads.

That's the code behind page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    input_box.Text = Request.QueryString["input"];
}
protected void run(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = string.Format("?input={0}", input_box.Text);
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath + url);
}
```

Problem is that when query string is not empty, string from input_box cannot be passed to query string. How to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand this correctlly

I think the the post back might be clearing your textbox before sending to the query string.
try adding this to the page load
       if (IsPostBack)
                return;

This will stop the inputbox being cleared or reset back to the original query string

Hope this help

Comment: IActually if(!IsPostBack) { //pageLoad event } is a solution to my problem.

Thanks for hinting!